# Create table generator in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to create a table generator in delphi 10, like the one in the picture.
I can't find any options to edit/add buttons the "column name, column type and column size".

[image: mockup screen capture]

```
procedure TForm1.AddColumnClick(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  Col : TColumn; 
begin
  Col := DBGrid2.Columns.Add; 
  Col.Title.Caption := 'MyNewColumn'; 
end;
```

If this is to add a column, how do I get the code for the column type and its size?

Comment: You don't.  You define the relevant properties of the fields in the table attached to the grid and the grid will automatically adjust to suit.

Comment: more exactly, how can i do it?

Comment: Depends on which database you are using.  Read the documentation for it.

Comment: however if you could help me with some more specific information I would be grateful

Comment: There is no simple answer to this, it all depends on the database you are using.  You know that but I don't.

Comment: I want to do it from 0, what database should I use?

Comment: Up to you.  It is specifically off-topic here at SO to ask for recommendations for software.

Comment: If you don't need specific line header in your component you could also use TListView and set it Style to vsReport as this gives you access to column headers [TListItemSubItems example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/TListItemSubItems_(Delphi))

Comment: procedure TForm1.AddColumnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Col : TColumn;
begin
  Col := DBGrid2.Columns.Add;
  Col.Title.Caption := 'MyNewColumn';
end;
if this is to add a column, how do i get the code for the column type and its size

Comment: @LoganGarmon Put that comment in your question.

Comment: Please look for some elementary tutorial on the net. Search for, e.g. `delphi creating data base applications`. You can not hope for much success until you know how the db and its structure relates to the user interface components.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit which asks

> how do I get the code for the column type and its size?

completely changes what your q is about.  It is still far too broad, and it seems that you are intent
on re-inventing the wheel, because Delphi's TDBGrid has the necessary facilities to do what you seem
to want built-in.  Here is my suggestion for further study:

- Learn how to create **persistent** TFields on your dataset which will be supplying
  the data for the grid. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Persistent_Field_Components
  The pont of doing this is that once the dataset has persistent TFields, the design-time
  facilities supporting the creation of TDBGrid columns become available.
- Once your dataset has persistent TFields, in the IDE clear any columns the
  TDBGrid already has, then
- Double-click on the DBgrid.  You will get a pop-up columns editor with a caption like
  `Editing  DBGrid1.Columns`.  Right click in the columns editor and select `Add All Fields` from
  the context menu.  That will create the columns withthe default datatypes and sizes that Delphi
  uses for the grid's columns, which is what you seem to be trying to do yourself.

To answer your specific question, you can get the size and datatype of a field of the dataset using

```
AField := DBGrid1.Columns[i].Field;
Size := AField.Size;
DataType := AField.DataType;
```

Working out how to set a suitable column width from the Size of the associated TField is left as an exercise to the reader.

You need to study the source code of TDBGrid to see how the grid columns adapt their behaviour
  to the specific TField types of the dataset.

To assist in that, add a button to your form and the following code

```
type
 TMyDBGrid = class(TDBGrid);

procedure TForm1.btnCreateColumnsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.Columns.Clear;
  TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).CreateColumns;
end;
```

The TMyGrid type declaration is to get access to the protected `CreateColumns` method
  of the grid.  You can then put a debuuger breakpoint on the TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).CreateColumns
  call and trace into it to see what it does.

Good luck!

Comment: Did this answer your q?